# How to run custom framework selenium script from Hiptest?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, teamcity

I have selenium scripts which are written on a Selenium-Maven-TestNG framework.

How can I configure these scripts with Hiptest and run them from Hiptest directly?

I am using Bitbucket as repository and TeamCity as CI Tool. Is it possible to link TeamCity with Hiptest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hiptest has an external test run feature designed to import and track the execution results of your existing test suites in your project.
Have a look at this page of the documentation:

https://docs.hiptest.net/create-a-test-run-for-your-unit-tests/

Then, just add the Curl commands in the build script of your TeamCity job, and it should work :)